# Change ListViewItems Layout with a Right Swipe. Android

Tags: android, animation, swipe, viewflipper, listviewitem

i've now got the listview and it's touch actions and swipe actions working. But now i'm not sure how i can implement a swipe effect, like it's in the twitter app.

I've found in the internet that it's possible to animate 2 views with a viewflipper, but is it possible to animate two layouts in the same way?

Anyone out there, who knows how i can implement such a function?

The only thing i want is to switch the ListViewsItem layout with a swipe.

Comment: I would guess that they used a ViewFlipper as the root for their row.xml layout file. And yes you use it to switch between Layouts as well. Technically RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc.. are Views. I must be honest though, the swipe functionality in the twitter app does not work all that great for me. I can get it to swipe over and show the 5 options, but getting it to swipe back doesn't seem to work nearly as well. I would think that LongClick would've been a better way to go.

Comment: yes i tried this but any ideas on how i can implement this?

Comment: swipe or longclick isn't the problem. my problem is how to implement such a viewflipper correct. so cann you please give me a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, set both the item views in 2 separate thread and then start both of them.

Comment: i can't undersand what this has to do with a viewflipper?